# Generate two diferents pdf from the same url using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, pdf, phantomjs

I want to generate 2 diferents pdf from the same url (http://www.ensaiosclinicos.gov.br/rg/RBR-8c33jx/)

One pdf is in portuguese and other one in english. To set the language manually i have to click on the link PT or EN on the top right of the screen.

This link is a javascript action.

I am using this command to generate the PDF:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js 'http://www.ensaiosclinicos.gov.br/rg/RBR-8c33jx/' RBR-8c33jx3.pdf 1200*600
```

that i found here at https://coderwall.com/p/5vmo1g/use-phantomjs-to-create-pdfs-from-html.

Is it possible to use emulate the click in the link PT and EN in the phantomjs code to change the language and generate 2 pdfs?